# C++ 2 nested for loops transform to recursion

Tags: c, recursion

Hi i wanted to tranform this code into a recursive function:

```
int a3(int* a, int length) {
   if(a == 0 || length <= 0) return 0;
   int sum = 0;
   for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      for(int j = i; j < length; j++) {
         sum += a[j];
      }
   }
   return sum;
}
```

My approach is :

```
int rec_help(int*a, int length);

int a3(int* a, int length) {
    if(a == 0 || length <= 0) return 0;
else{
    return rec_help(a,length) + rec_help(a+1,length-1) ;
    }
}

int rec_help(int*a, int length){
    if(a == 0 || length <= 0) return 0;
    else{
        int tmp = a[0];
        return tmp + a3(a+1,length-1);
    }
}
```

But i'm not getting it right.

With a3() i wanted to simulate the first for loop, and i think there is my problem :D

And with rec_help() the second loop and the body, but im mixing things here.

I would appreciate any kind of help :)

Comment: Would you mind changing the tags to C instead of C++?

Comment: i added C tag if that's ok?

Comment: If you use a C compiler tag the question C, if you use a C++ compiler tag the question C++. Adjust the question's title accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have 2 loop, if you want your function to be recursive, you will need 2 recursive functions, one which will do the job of the first loop and a second to do the job of your second loop...

Something like that should work :

```
int a3_rec(int *a, int length)
{
    if (length == 0)
        return (0);
   return (*a + a3_rec(a + 1, length - 1));
}

int a3_rec_hat(int *a, int length)
{
    if (a == 0 || length == 0)
        return (0);
    return (a3_rec(a, length) + a3_rec_hat(a + 1, length - 1));
}
```

I hope I've helped you :)

Comment: happy to hear it :)

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, when you transform loops into recursion, every loop becomes a function and any non-local variables it uses become arguments.

Your original code is

```
int a3(int* a, int length) {
   if(a == 0 || length <= 0) return 0;
   int sum = 0;
   for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      for(int j = i; j < length; j++) {
         sum += a[j];
      }
   }
   return sum;
}
```

Let's start with the innermost loop. It uses `j`, `i`, `length`, `sum`, and `a` from the surrounding scope.

```
void a3_loop0(int *pj, int length, int *psum, int *a) {
    if (*pj < length) {
        *psum += a[*pjj];
        (*pj)++;
        a3_loop0(pj, length, psum, a);
    }
}

int a3(int* a, int length) {
    if(a == 0 || length <= 0) return 0;
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        int j = i;
        a3_loop0(&j, length, &sum, a);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

This is a very literal and mechanical translation. Every mutable variable has become a pointer (in C++ you'd use references for this), which leads to somewhat ugly and non-functional code (well, code that doesn't use idiomatic functional style). But it works, and we can proceed to the next loop in the same way:

```
void a3_loop0(int *pj, int length, int *psum, int *a) {
    if (*pj < length) {
        *psum += a[*pj];
        (*pj)++;
        a3_loop0(pj, length, psum, a);
    }
}

void a3_loop1(int *pi, int length, int *psum, int *a) {
    if (*pi < length) {
        int j = *pi;
        a3_loop0(&j, length, psum, a);
        (*pi)++;
        a3_loop1(pi, length, psum, a);
    }
}

int a3(int* a, int length) {
    if(a == 0 || length <= 0) return 0;
    int sum = 0;
    int i = 0;
    a3_loop1(&i, length, &sum, a);
    return sum;
}
```

Technically we're done now, but there's a number of things we can clean up.

The first thing I'd do is to change the type of `a` to `const int *` because `a3` never modifies any of its elements.

The second thing I'd do is to hoist the loop variables `*pi` / `*pj` into their functions; they don't really need to be pointers to mutable objects elsewhere.

```
void a3_loop0(int j, int length, int *psum, const int *a) {
    if (j < length) {
        *psum += a[j];
        a3_loop0(j + 1, length, psum, a);
    }
}

void a3_loop1(int i, int length, int *psum, const int *a) {
    if (i < length) {
        a3_loop0(i, length, psum, a);
        a3_loop1(i + 1, length, psum, a);
    }
}

int a3(const int *a, int length) {
    if (a == 0 || length <= 0) return 0;
    int sum = 0;
    a3_loop1(0, length, &sum, a);
    return sum;
}
```

This already simplifies and shortens the code a bit.

The next step is to actually return something from these helper functions. Currently they use `*psum` as an accumulator and return `void`. We can keep the use of an accumulator but return the result directly (instead of through an output parameter) as follows:

```
void a3_loop0(int j, int length, int sum, const int *a) {
    if (j < length) {
        return a3_loop0(j + 1, length, sum + a[j], a);
    }
    return sum;  // this was implicit before; "return sum unchanged"
}

void a3_loop1(int i, int length, int sum, const int *a) {
    if (i < length) {
        return a3_loop1(i + 1, length, a3_loop0(i, length, sum, a), a);
    }
    return sum;  // ditto
}

int a3(const int *a, int length) {
    if (a == 0 || length <= 0) return 0;
    return a3_loop1(0, length, 0, a);
}
```

This version of the code is "purely functional" in that it never modifies any variables; it only passes and returns values to and from functions, respectively.

If we wanted to, we could get rid of all `if` statements and write everything as expressions:

```
void a3_loop0(int j, int length, int sum, const int *a) {
    return j < length
        ? a3_loop0(j + 1, length, sum + a[j], a)
        : sum;
}

void a3_loop1(int i, int length, int sum, const int *a) {
    return i < length
        ? a3_loop1(i + 1, length, a3_loop0(i, length, sum, a), a)
        : sum;
}

int a3(const int *a, int length) {
    return a == 0 || length <= 0
        ? 0
        : a3_loop1(0, length, 0, a);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your in detail answer, it's astonishing in how many ways you can create recursion's :)

Answer (score 0):

I'll post this because I see the other answers use 1 function per loop which isn't necessary.

You can have just 1 recursive function:

```
int a3_impl(int* a, int length, int i, int j)
{
    if (i >= length)
        return 0;

    if (j >= length)
        return a3_impl(a, length, i + 1, i + 1);

    return a[j] + a3_impl(a, length, i, j + 1);
}

int a3(int* a, int length)
{
    if(a == 0 || length <= 0)
        return 0;

    return a3_impl(a, length, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, guys you are opening my eyes :D